# Crystal Reports, convert number value to minutes (time) for formula

Tags: crystal-reports

Working with Crystal Reports 2016, datasource is SQL Server 2008 R2.  I'm new to Crystal Reports. Right now, I am stuck working on a problem where I need to compute a start time, if I have an end time and a length.  In the database is an end time in time format, and a length, in number format.  The number is how long something was active (think, how log a meeting was), in minutes.  I need to subtract the length from the time value, but am running into a type mismatch and can't seem to convert properly.

I tried using `TimeValue()` to convert the number to a time value, but the Formula Workshop says that there's an error, and that there should be a number in place of `{CRV_UsageLog.Data5}`.  I'm not sure if I have a logic problem or a syntax problem.  This is what I am trying to do:

```
ShiftDateTime ({CRV_UsageLog.LogTimeStamp} - TimeValue(0,{CRV_UsageLog.Data5},0), "GMT,0,GMT" ,"" )
```

`CRV_UsageLog.LogTimeStamp` is the time field, and `CRV_UsageLog.Data5` is a value representing minutes.  I'd like to subtract the latter from the former to get the start time so that I can display the start time in my report.

Do I need to encapsulate or escape `CRV_UsageLog.Data5` in some manner?  Do I need a different function?

The time looks like this: 2016-06-22 13:21:21.247

The number looks like this: 21

I'd like my computed value to look like this: 2016-06-22 13:00:21.247

Comment: Show expected data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wound up doing, as a formula:

```
ShiftDateTime(DateAdd("n", -{CRV_UsageLog.Data5}, {CRV_UsageLog.LogTimeStamp}), "GMT,0,GMT" ,"" )
```